# Работа с файлами, циклы python

Tags: python, файлы

Есть следующий код:

```
import os
path = r'C:\filename'
files = os.listdir(path)

for file in files:
    print(file)
```

Допустим у нас в папке 9 файлов с именами '1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'. Каким образом нужно написать цикл, чтобы за цикл он печатал по три файла? В первом цикле на выходе: 1 2 3, во втором 4,5,6, в третьем 7,8,9

---

Хорошо, спасибо, но у меня все равно не получилось перенести эту идею на мой код. Смотри, мне нужно импортировать 3 последовательных видео из папки в видеоредактор. Есть следующий код:

```
import os
from pywinauto import keyboard
path = r'C:\action_in_past'
files = os.listdir(path)

for file in range(0, len(files), 3):
     # Вводим в строку импорта 3 разных файла 

     keyboard.send_keys(file)
     keyboard.send_keys(file)
     keyboard.send_keys(file)
```

Я надеюсь, ты понял мою идею

Answer (score 1):

так требуется?

```
files = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]

for index in range(0, len(files), 3):
    print(files[index:index + 3])
```

основная идея -

1. идем в цикле от 0 до размера списка `len(files)` с шагом 3 - `range(0, len(files), 3)`
2. на каждом этапе цикла от списка с текущей позиции отрезаем кусочек размером 3, т.е. делаем срез списка `files[index:index + 3]`

таким образом получаются списки от 0 до 3 позиции, от 3 до 6, от 6 до 9, от 9 до ... и т.д.

**P.S.**

```
files = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]

for index in range(0, len(files), 3):
    selected_files = files[index:index + 3]

    # обработать файлы
    for file in selected_files:
         keyboard.send_keys(file)

    # сделать что-то еще

    # удалить файлы
    for file in selected_files:
        os.remove(file)
```

Comment: Да, спасибо огромное, то что нужно. А можешь, пожалуйста, пояснить этот код?

Comment: добавил в свой комментарий пояснение

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, но у меня все равно не получилось перенести эту идею на мой код. Смотри, мне нужно импортировать 3 последовательных видео из папки в видеоредактор. Есть следующий код:

import os
from pywinauto import keyboard
path = r'C:\action_in_past'
files = os.listdir(path)

for file in range(0, len(files), 3):
     # Вводим в строку импорта 3 разных файла 

     keyboard.send_keys(file)
     keyboard.send_keys(file)
     keyboard.send_keys(file)
Я надеюсь, ты понял мою идею

Comment: не совсем понял - надо за раз сделать 3 последовательных вызова `keyboard.send_keys`? или сформировать 1 вызов, но строки, содержащей 3 пути к файлам (например через `;`)?

Comment: смотри, мне нужно за цикл импортировать три идущих подряд видео из папки, затем в этом же цикле эти ролики зарендерить (рендер - процесс создания ролика), а затем удалить эти 3 ролика с дорожки. это весь цикл. и так делаем до тех пор, пока не пройдемся по всем роликам. то есть мне нужно чтобы на каждый новый keyboard.send_keys печаталось название отличное от предыдущего

Comment: ну тогда внутри цикла который формирует списки из 3 элементов сделать просто еще и цикл по каждому из этих 3х элементов чтобы сделать `send`, а затем еще и удалить - в общем работать со списком из 3 элементов просто

Comment: можешь написать, как ты это видишь? без удаления пока что, просто чтобы печатало по 3 разных файла

Comment: добавил в своем ответе код после PS

Comment: спасибо, это понял. а как сделать так, чтобы мы импортировали ровно три видео, затем перешли к другому циклу? а то получается так, что сначала импортируются все видео, и только потом работает следующий цикл.

Comment: почему? мы сначала получаем список всех файлов, дальше разбиваем файлы на тройки и вот с этими тройками можем делать что хотим, т.е. большой цикл идет по списку файлов и формирует тройки, малый цикл уже по файлам из троек. Или надо что-то еще? Я поэтому и спросил - на обработку надо как-то закидывать сразу по 3 пути? тогда какой формат чтобы сформировать правильно такой запрос? главное - есть список из 3 файлов, дальше делайте с ним что хотите. Или требуется что-то иное?

Comment: все, наконец-то до меня дошло. спасибо вам огромное!